# Type assertion for TypeList in terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform

I'm writing a Terraform provider and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do type assertion when I have a TypeList containing elements of TypeString.

The resouce is defined as follows:

```
    return &schema.Resource{
        Create: resourceConfigObjectCreate,
        Read:   resourceConfigObjectRead,
        Update: resourceConfigObjectUpdate,
        Delete: resourceConfigObjectDelete,

        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "name": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
            },
            "notification_options": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeList,
                Optional: true,
                Elem: schema.Schema{
                    Type:             schema.TypeString,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```

And i would like to load those values to a custom type defined like that:

```
type ConfigObject struct {
    Name                        string   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    NotificationOptions         []string `json:"notification_options,omitempty"`

}
```

Since schema.ResourceData.Get returns an interface{} a type assertion is needed.

```
    item := thruk.ConfigObject{
        Name: schema.ResourceData.Get("name").(string),
        NotificationOptions: extractSliceOfStrings(schema.ResourceData.Get("notification_options")),
    }
```

I've done it easily for string but the slice of strings was more complex and I created the following function:

```
func extractSliceOfStrings(i interface{}) (slice []string) {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if !s.IsValid() {
        return
    }
    for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
        slice = append(slice, s.Index(i).String())
    }
    return
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: According to your code, you are already specifying a type of `list` containing elements of `string`, which is what you are asking for. what is your question besides that?

Comment: Thanks for the checking my question. The problem I had is that `schema.ResourceData` returns an interface type and I need to convert it to the proper type. Type asserting works with string but not with slice.
While trying to write some log in order to answer you I came up with something that seems working: 
```func extractSliceOfStrings(i interface{}) (slice []string) {
 s := reflect.ValueOf(i)
 if !s.IsValid() {
  return
 }
 for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
  slice = append(slice, s.Index(i).String())
 }
 return
}```
but i'm still not sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: @MattSchuchard , I just edited the question in order to make it more clear. I also took the chance to fix a couple of typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with the `ResourceData` API in a Terraform provider, it's helpful to know which Go type corresponds to each of the schema types. You've already inferred that `schema.TypeString` corresponds to `string`. Here's a complete list:

- `TypeBool` ⇒ `bool`
- `TypeString` ⇒ `string`
- `TypeInt` ⇒ `int`
- `TypeList` ⇒ `[]interface{}`
- `TypeMap` ⇒ `map[string]interface{}`
- `TypeSet` ⇒ `*schema.Set`
- Element type when `Elem` is set to a `*schema.Resource`: `map[string]interface{}`

The translations above are documented on the [Schema Types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/schemas/schema-types.html) documentation page for the SDK, as "Data structure:" under each of the headings.

Whenever you are dealing with a collection, the element type from Go's perspective is always `interface{}` to reflect the fact that the element type isn't decided until runtime. However, the same mapping rules defined above apply to those element values too, and so to convert a `TypeList` whose `Elem` is a `TypeString` you'd first assert the slice type, and then assert each element in turn:

```golang
itemsRaw := d.Get("example").([]interface{})
items := make([]string, len(itemsRaw))
for i, raw := range itemsRaw {
    items[i] = raw.(string)
}
```

Unfortunately there is no way to go directly from `[]interface{}` to `[]string` in a single step, due to the design of Go interfaces and type assertions.

You can take a similar approach for `TypeMap`, if you ultimately need `map[string]string`:

```golang
itemsRaw := d.Get("example").(map[string]interface{})
items := make(map[string]string, len(itemsRaw))
for k, raw := range itemsRaw {
    items[k] = raw.(string)
}
```

`TypeSet` is a little more complicated due to the custom `*schema.Set` container, but you can call the `List` method of the set to obtain a `[]interface{}` which you can then treat the same as with `TypeList` above:

```golang
itemsRaw := d.Get("example").(*schema.Set).List()
items := make([]string, len(itemsRaw))
for i, raw := range itemsRaw {
    items[i] = raw.(string)
}
```